# How do I inject a property of a primitive type using Ninject?

Tags: ninject

How do I inject the name "Tommy" into the `Name` property of Bar when instantiating / activating a `Foo` object?

```
class Foo
    {
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }

        public Foo(Bar b) { Bar = b; }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        [Inject]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kernel.Bind<Bar>().ToSelf().WithPropertyValue("Name", "Tommy");
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this is more refactor-safe:

```
kernel.Bind<Bar>().ToSelf().OnActivation(bar => bar.Name = "Tommy");
```

but beware, you should only use property injection when there's no alternatives. Objects should be built up by the constructor - i.E. after the constructor was run they should have all they need to operate. So maybe you should inject the value into the constructor instead.